# Exit a loop when Assertion is true

Tags: loops, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, assertions

I'm using a MailReaderSampler which gets all the messages from given email ID. All the emails have a verification token in it. For now, the token is being passed on the subject of the mail.

**So the Response Data will have**:

`Date:-- 
To: --
From: --
Subject: token : someToken`

I have defined a Token value in `User Defined Variables` and I'm using `Response assertion` to check if the mail contains the **Token**.

So it checks for all the sub-results(all emails). Now whenever an email contains the token, then **I want to stop the test and the assertion condition should not check in other emails as it already found the email which has token value**.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, but I haven't tried it yet... Add BeanShell sampler after your mail sampler with following code.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;

SampleResult[] subResults = JMeterContextService.getContext().getPreviousResult().getSubResults();
for(SampleResult sr : subResults) {
    if (sr.getResponseDataAsString().contains(vars.get("Token").toString()))
        JMeterContextService.getContext().getEngine().stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Ivan Markovic: It worked. Thank you.I also want to include a dummy sampler, get the result of the mail(even if the token matches or not) and do the assertions for that result. So instead of stopping the test, can we add a variable, store result in it and pass it to dummy sampler for assertions?

Comment: No problem mate. Just tell me if you wanna get only the token as a result, or every message? Btw, any assertions can be done in Beanshell Sampler or we could even make our own response for BS sampler and you can assert it...?

Answer (score 0):

you can use MailReaderSampler inside WHILE Controller and the condition for WHILE controller should be as:

```
${__javaScript("${userDefinedTokens}" != "tokensFromEmail",)}
```

the while loop will exit when your expected token is equal to token from an email.

userDefinedTokens: you define your token
tokensFromEmail: you extract token from email using either regex extractor or JSON extractor