# Reading message content from Email

Tags: jmeter

Using Jmeter, I want to extract OTP from email that i got in my gmail account.

My problem is:
I am not able to read content from child of sub-sampler response in the View Results Tree.
  Check below image
  [Listener for Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOwau.png)
I am using Regular Expression Extractor to extract value.

Comment: This could potentially be helpful for you. [StackOverflowQuestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109597/exit-a-loop-when-assertion-is-true/38143138#38143138)

Comment: @IvanMarkovic, The solution is working for when we need to get subject,to,from. But when we need to extract data from message body, then what to do. Also the body comes as child of subsample( For e.g-> Message 1 contains child that contains message body). Please check the attached screenshot in the question. Please help me out from this problem

Comment: As I understood, you could even check sub-result of sub-result. Just expand the code to obtain data from the sub-sub-result. ;-)

Comment: How can I obtain the data from sub-sub-result. Can u please explain. @IvanMarkovic. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Got an alternative Solution. Just Check the option "Store the message using MIME" and then you will get you message body in the sub-sample.

Comment: Here is the attachment: [link] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxbUKAl9oP-BN2RGSW5LYnFPR2c/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to switch your [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) scope to `Main sample and sub-samples` or `Sub-samples only`

[image]

See [How To Create A JMeter Script To Check Email During Registration AND Grab The Confirmation URL](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733729-How-to-Create-a-JMeter-Script-to-Check-Email-During-Registration-AND-Grab-the-Confirmation-URL) article for more details if required

Comment: I tried this, but this did not work for child of sub-sample. This work upto child  of main sample only